# Performance issue on React-native V0.42

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded my project from version 0.37 to version 0.42. I do not have to change any source code but my app is so slow now. My app is small and does not have much data.

Do you guys have same problem?

Do you have any suggestions to solve it?

Comment: I am not up to rn .42 at the moment but did you enable your debug mode maybe through the new update ? Try to deaktivate through shaking your phone and go to options "Dev Settings" - Under "JS Dev Mode" you can deaktivate the debug mode.

Comment: Thank you  Jonathan Stellwag, but I think it relates to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11809